# Система приза раз в 4 часа

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Хочу сделать систему получения приза в телеграмм боте(telebot), знаю как сделать все в этой системе, кроме как вывода сообщения о кулдауне в 4 часа в формате (часы:минуты) на использование команды получения приза. Как лучше сделать такой вывод кулдауна и как настроить под это строчку в базе данных?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, это можно реализовать очень просто. По моему мнению, самым банальным решением является хранение даты и времени последнего приза, и отталкивание от него.

То есть, у пользователя будет поле, например, `last_achievement_datetime`, и каждый раз при вызове команды `/get_prize` (или как она у вас называется), будет вызываться функция проверки (`is_cooldown_over`), которая будет проверять, прошло ли 4 часа или нет. Если не прошло, то отправлять сообщение, что сейчас нельзя получить приз, и возвращаться через X часов Y минут.

Вот пример:

```py
# Функция для проверки кулдауна
def is_cooldown_over(user_id):
    current_user = get_user_by_id(user_id)
    last_achievement_datetime = current_user.last_achievement_datetime

    # Если пользователь новый или нет записи о времени последнего приза, значит кулдаун не пройден
    if not last_achievement_datetime:
        return True  
    
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    cooldown_time = last_achievement_datetime[0] + datetime.timedelta(hours=4)

    # Проверяем прошло ли нужное количество времени или нет
    return current_time >= cooldown_time

# Обработчик команды для получения приза
@bot.message_handler(commands=['get_prize'])
def get_prize(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id

    if is_cooldown_over(user_id):
        # Тут обновляем время последнего приза
        current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
        update_user_latest_achievement_datetime(user_id, current_datetime)
        
        # Дальше код выдачи приза
        ...
        
        bot.send_message(user_id, "Поздравляю! Вы получили свой приз.")
    else:
        # Иначе выводим сообщение о кулдауне, и то сколько осталось до выдачи следющего приза
        current_user = get_user_by_id(user_id)
        last_achievement_datetime = current_user.last_achievement_datetime
        
        # Вычисляем то сколько осталось до окончания кулдауна
        time_until_cooldown = (last_achievement_datetime + datetime.timedelta(hours=4) - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds()
        hours, remainder = divmod(time_until_cooldown, 3600)
        minutes = remainder // 60
        
        # Отправляем сообщение
        bot.send_message(user_id, f"Вы уже получили приз. Пожалуйста, подождите {int(hours)} часов {int(minutes)} минут, чтобы получить приз снова.")
```

Comment: это же не подключение через бд